# how to set multiple angular material datepickers' state invalid based on global /parent component's condition

Tags: angular6, angular-moment, angular-material-6

There are 2 datepickers (angular material datepickers) wrapped in a child component. I am trying to set both datepickers's state to invalid or red underlined if date difference is more than 2 days (X days).

Currently it only marks the field which user is interacting with. 
What would be the best way to achieve that? Main form is template driven and using reactive technique inside the datepicker component. Though it lists the errors below but i want to highlight both fields with red for UX sake.
Here is the fiddle for the code. 
[Fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepicker-wrapper-reactive-7ai1ct?file=src/app/app.component.ts)